# Huawei G7 No network-No service problem

Tags: huawei, sim-card

Hy there, I am facing an issue, My Sim card automatically disconnects after some time... And reconnects automatically without doing anything...without even physically bothering the phone. And when it works, it gives full 3G signals. And when it works, I can also make calls and use my data... What could be the problem? It says no network-No service... Ofcourse My network provider service is pretty nice in my area.. Issue is with phone, I just need an idea what could be wrong with my phone? Plz help

Comment: even if not caused by move it may be loosen or dirty contacts in sim tray, or sim card is not well positioned